# Pass a typescript class method as a callback

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use Typescript on Firebase Functions, defining a class that has a method I want to pass as a callback to export the function code.
I've tried this:

```
class Foo {
  bar (data) { return data.bar; }
  handler(event) { return this.bar(event.data); }
}
```

On index.ts I've tried:

```
functions.pubsub.topic('subscriptions').onPublish(new Foo().handler);
```

but I get `cannot access property 'bar' of undefined`, which means `this` is undefined inside `handler`.

I then tried to use the call method as:

```
const fooInstance = new Foo()
functions.pubsub.topic('subscriptions').onPublish((event) => fooInstance.handler.call(fooInstance, event));
```

But I get the same error. I'm clueless right now. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version that should work... although I don't know what your `onPublish` expects, so I have captured the result in a variable for now as I don't know what you want to do with it.

```
functions.pubsub.topic('subscriptions').onPublish((event) => {
    const result = new Foo().handler(event);
});
```

Comment: Hey @Fenton, `onPublish` expects a function that returns a promise, so possibly this will indeed work. I'll report back.

Comment: Actually, my solution with the `call` worked well, but I'll use yours anyway, as it is more readable.